# Develop a Word to PDF converter from scratch without using 3rd party tools

Tags: c#, c++, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

Develop a Word to PDF converter from scratch without using ANY 3rd party tools. Need ideas of how actually we can develop this. Basically using C#/C++.

Comment: Which version of Word : .docx or .doc ? And do you have a few months of free time?

Comment: 1) Obtain and digest word-document specifications.  2) Obtain and digest PDF specifications.  3) Invest in coffee, and spend months rolling your own solution.  4) Give up, and purchase 3rd-party tool anyway.

Comment: Does "Word" itself count as a third party tool?  If so, are you seriously asking how you can develop something that can parse and render a Word document from scratch?

Comment: benjymous then how 3rd party organizations develop such applications from scratch?

Comment: Both formats doc and docx.

Comment: You talk about *we*. Are you a big team with a big budget. Then your project might be feasible.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do this without third party tools/libraries?

Answer (score 5):

1. Buy Coffee
2. Learn PDF Specification: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html
3. Learn DOC Specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx
4. Learn DOCX Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm
5. Have mental breakdown
6. Spend 2 years writing own solution
7. Spend 6 months undergoing psychological treatment
8. Buy 3rd Party Tool
9. Profit? Nope (Profit wasted from trying to do it yourself)

Comment: Time is not a constraint, just need ideas of how to start.

Comment: @Skyrim Learn the specifications :) Thats where to start.

Comment: Hmmm Thanks a lot Ashigore....

Comment: Actually the list does not yet contain reality checks... documents in the wild might deviate somewhat from the specification in mysterious ways. Specifications have the tendency to be misunderstood in details.

Comment: @mkl This wasn't intended as a serious step-by-step guide... it was a joke! In reality, it would be pretty much impossible for one developer to complete to any decent standard.

Comment: @Ashigore - whilst tongue-in-cheek, it's pretty accurate.  You've also missed the step where one would come up with their own "format-agnostic" format in the interim, rather than attempting to go directly from one format to the other.

Comment: Ya thats true. So there is no other choice. If we need to use such functionality there is no such quick (Free :) ) way to achieve it.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I want to ask if I remove the 'word' part from it and only concentrate on parsing PDF files, is it practically possible for one person?

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal However the exact format won't be matched if you follow such procedure. Hmm yes the data would be intact in such pdf file.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, it would be *simpler* but still complicated and time-consuming.  Sure, it's possible - the real question is "How long have you got?".  There is a reason that good and free PDF converters are thin on the ground - because the investment in to these converters is considerable and not to be trifled with.  It's not just understanding the PDF format - it's ensuring that the final representation is a facsimile of the original content.  This is an area of software-engineering where off-the-shelf is practically always the way forward.

Comment: @Ashigore I didn't assume it to be serious... but the fun of files not-quite-as-specified should not be left out of the joke  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you can't do that while staying within a reasonable budget: it would take years to develop.

[Here's more information why.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html)